# Fine tuning a regular expression

Tags: javascript, liferay

I have a requirement for password policy which should have

1. At least one lowercase letter
2. At least one uppercase letter
3. At least one number
4. At least one special character
5. Minimum 8 and maximum 20 characters
6. And any three combinations of the above mentioned top 4 points

So I came up with a regular expression which is of 192 characters length and is working fine. But our database has the limitation to store only 75 characters of regular expression. How can I finetune this to maximum of 75 characters length. Here is my regular expression.

```
(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@\/#$%&=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\/#$%&=?_.,:;\\-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\/#$%&=?_.,:;\\-])).{6,12})
```

Comment: `(((?=.*[A-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@\/#$%&=?_.,:;\\-])).{8,20})` how about this? i dont understand why you need 4 OR condition

Comment: @QuyTruong I am not sure if I am making my point clear in 6th point by saying "any three combinations". I will try to explain here. I have four sets 

1. a-z
2. A-Z
3. 0-9
4. !@/#$%&=?_.,:;\-

Then _Xaviers1_ can be a password. The password should not contain all the four sets, any 3 combinations of 4 sets should do.

Comment: I see. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Whenever someone imposes a maximum length of passwords, I'm assuming they're storing the passwords in a VARCHAR(20) column in plain text. I've never understood this limitation. And elaborated password policies like this typically only annoy the users, instead of enforcing great passwords. I'd rather advise to give a "strength meter" that visualizes password strength when a new password is entered. This way you educate your users on proper passwords. And remove the length limitation: You're hashing the password anyway.